# Documentdb Failed to deserialize stored procedure response or convert it to my defined type

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

My Stored Procedure: (I created it via Azure Script Explorer)

```
function GetAllResources() {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();

// Query documents and take 1st item.
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    'SELECT * FROM MultiLanguage as m',
    function (err, docs, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!docs || !docs.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
        else getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(docs));
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

The sproc can be executed successfully from script explorer.

My C# code to call the sproc:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult>  GetReources() {
        client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
        var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);

        //var docs = await client.ReadDocumentFeedAsync(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 });


        //var docs = from d in client.CreateDocumentQuery<Models.Resource>(collectionLink)
        //           select d;

        StoredProcedure storedProcedure = client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collectionLink).Where(c => c.Id == "GetAllResources").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

        Models.Resource docs = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Models.Resource>(storedProcedure.SelfLink);


        foreach (var d in docs) {
            Models.Resource a = new Models.Resource();
            a = docs;
            //a.id = d.id;
            //a.Scenario = d.Scenario;
            //a.Translations = d.Translations;
            //a.LastModified = d.LastModified;
            //a.ModifiedBy = d.ModifiedBy;
            //a.LastAccessed = d.LastAccessed;

            resources.Add(a);
        }



        return Ok(resources);
    }
```

First, there is an error for the "foreach..." like said

> foreach cannot operate on variables of type Models.Resource because it
>   doesn't contain a public definition of GetEnumerator.

Then I tried to modify my sproc to only return 1 result and remove the foreach line, then I got error said

> Failed to deserialize stored procedure response or convert it to type
>   'Models.Resource'

I just want to return the result of the stored procedure as my defined class (Models.Resource). How to do this?

Comment: Not that it's "the" error, but in your `foreach` you're trying to assign `a` to `docs` instead of `d`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo when I copying...It should be a = d;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, let's make sure we are on the same page.

I am using the sproc same as above.
I am using client code like this:

```
    class Models
    {
        // This would have more properties, I am just using id which all docs would have.
        public class Resource
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetResources()
    {
        const string endpoint = "https://myservice.azure.com:443/";
        const string authKey = "my secret key==";

        var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey);
        Uri sprocUri = UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("db", "c1", "GetAllResources");

        var serializedDocs = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(sprocUri);
        Models.Resource[] resources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Resource[]>(serializedDocs);

        return Ok(resources);
    }
```

It works fine. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Thank you Michael! I just realized that my"foreach" line error comes from the reason that I missed "[]" around the Model.Resources. By copying what you suggested, I have my demo running now. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler to get sproc by name using CreateStoredProcedureUri, like this:

```
        const string endpoint = "https://your.service.azure.com:443/";
        const string authKey = "<your magic secret master key>==";

        var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey);
        Uri sprocUri = UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("databaseName", "collectionName", "GetAllResources");

        var result = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(sprocUri);
```

The stored procedure above serializes results of the query (docs array) to string, if you keep it this way, the result of sproc would be string, which I guess you would need to manually deserialize to objects. You can do this simpler, just return docs from sproc and have result as objects (like Models.Resource[]), serialization would happen automatically.

If you change the sproc to return just one doc (e.g. do `__.response.setBody(docs[0]`) and Models.Resource represent one item, then the call is correct:

```
Models.Resource doc = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Models.Resource>(sprocUri);
```

Also, to // Query documents and take 1st item, I wouldn't recommend to use script as script has overhead of running JavsScript engine. Scripts kick in when you have bulk operations (to optimize for network traffic) or have business logic which makes sense to run on the server. To take 1st item you can do query from client like this: SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c. Typically you would WHERE and ORDER BY clause to that.

There is a number of docdb samples on github, for instance, https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/code-samples/ServerSideScripts and https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/code-samples/Queries.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael! I did exactly what you suggested and still the "docs" on the foreach line showing the "GetEnumerator" error, and the stored procedure result still can't be deserialized even I return docs as objects  <br/> BTW, the reason I create this sproc is because I want to speed up performance. I have been using Linq, Linq Lamda and SQL to query some small documents, call it via Web API from Postman. The thing is all of them take around 500ms+ for single select query. We need faster than that. That's why I'm trying sproc. Do you have any suggestion about speeding up the query? Thanks!